# Could tidal effects make matter hot enough for nuclear fusion?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, fusion, tidal-effect

There was a recent question about [cosmological firewalls](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38005/what-are-cosmological-firewalls).  Putting aside questions of entanglement and information and looking at the problem from a pure mechanical viewpoint, we know that although there is little perceptible radiation emitted from the blackhole, the tidal forces approaching the event horizon are enormous leading to [spaghettificaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification). Although the tensile forces will eventually tear a person apart, there are also compressive forces for material located in the same plane.

A human body contains a considerable amount of [hydrogen and other lighter elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_the_human_body). Would the compressive effects of spaghettification be sufficiently high to cause any of the hydrogen or other elements to fuse prior to reaching the event horizon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidal effects are not necessarily large at the event horizon. The tidal forces decrease as the black hole gets bigger, so for a big enough black hole the tidal forces at the event horizon can be insignificant. However the tidal forces always become infinitely large as you approach the singularity.

But I can answer a slight variation of your question. The accretion disk round a black hole gets heated by frictional interactions and can become hot enough for atoms to fuse. This isn't sustained fusion as happens in a the core of a star because the density is too low for that. However fusion can occur leading to nucleosynthesis. See for example http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2673.