# Topological Solitons and the Higgs Condensate entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, higgs

While focusing on resolutions to the [Firewall controversy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38005/what-are-cosmological-firewalls), and the possible implications of the Higgs field as it relates to the issue, the [possibility of using EPR correlations in the Higgs condensate to explain the absence of solitons in cosmology was encountered](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0204154).  The probability of phase transition without formation of the domain walls is derived to be:

$$ P^0_N = \dfrac{2}{[1+e^{-E/T}]^N + [1-e^{-E/T}]^N}$$

Where the effect is that high energy domain walls are highly suppressed from forming.

Is this sort of derivation been encountered before and in what context, and what issues may have been encountered in applying this logic to the issue of soliton formation?